# How to resolve OneDrive connection issues?

Tags: data-synchronization, login, big-sur

I have been having trouble with OneDrive on MBA M1 with macOS Big Sur v11.2.1 (even with the version of macOS MBA was shipped to me).

I have to login in again and again to make it work. It will randomly lose connection. Also, even when it isn't having login issues it is very very very slow. Every time I start it, it gets that rainbow pointer for several seconds (order of ~30 seconds).

Can anyone help me make it run without these issues?

Comment: Works here so it's probably not a M1 issue as such. Did you check whether you have the latest version?

Comment: Yes, it has been having this issue since the very beginning. I have also re-installed it at least once. So, at some point at the very least it was the latest version (currently as well) and the issues were there. Maybe my installation method is incorrect. How did you install it? I simply installed it through the App store.

Comment: I migrated everything from a previous Mac, don't think I did anything special for OneDrive. I would probably remove it, clean out any reference to OneDrive from ~/Library and install again. Not sure it helps though.

Comment: @nohillside It doesn't make a difference. Hopefully it will be fixed in a later version.